# NeumannValue and FiniteElement Methods : BC not respected

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I have noticed on several of my personal cases some issue with the BC using `NeumannValue`. 
Let me illustrate the problem.

I take the 1D example of `NeumannValue`

```
un = NDSolveValue[{D[-u[x], x, x] + 10 u[x] == 1 + NeumannValue[-1 + u[x], x == 1], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 0]}, u, {x, 0, 1}]
```

then I check if I do verify the BC 
`un[0] = 0`. So that is a good thing for DirichletConditions (seems to work properly)

Now the Robin condition: `un'[1] - (-1 + un[1]) = 0.00259342`

It is not correct... Ok zero is a little hard to ask but at least it should be of the order of machine errors

Moreover, if I use `NDSolve` instead :

```
un = u /.NDSolve[{D[-u[x], x, x] + 10 u[x] == 1, u'[1] == -1 + u[1],u[0] ==0}, u, 
  {x, 0, 1}][[1]]
```

I get

> ```
> un'[1] - (-1 + un[1]) = -3.16211*10^-7
> un[0] = 0.
> ```

Have you encounter similar issue? how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I continued Looking it up. It is possible to improve the result of NDSolveValue by reducing the mesh size : un = NDSolveValue[{D[-u[x], x, x] + 10 u[x] == 
    1 + NeumannValue[-1 + u[x], x == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 0]}, u, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001}}]

Comment: I think you could post your comment as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is, as you found out, to use a finer mesh:

```
un = NDSolveValue[{D[-u[x], x, x] + 10 u[x] == 
     1 + NeumannValue[-1 + u[x], x == 1], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 0]}, u, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001}}];
un'[1] - (-1 + un[1])
1.10517*10^-8
```